# Java, scala with gradle plugin in android studio

Tags: android, scala, android-studio

I saw the sample [here](https://github.com/saturday06/gradle-android-scala-plugin) to use scala with gradle plugin. I created a new android studio project. These are my gradle builds

**Project build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
        classpath "jp.leafytree.gradle:gradle-android-scala-plugin:1.4"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Module app build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "jp.leafytree.android-scala"
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ashwinxd.escalaandroidapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7"
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7"
    compile "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1"
    compile "org.scalaz:scalaz-core_2.11:7.1.0"
}
```

The project compiles fine. There is no `scala` src directory generated. How do I proceed with using scala alongside java files? Is it necessary to use them in a source directory called scala? If so how do I generate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your own `src/main/scala` directory. That is where the scala gradle plugin looks for the scala source files. Just like the android plugin will look at `src/main/java` and `src/androidTest/java`.

That page describes you can customize that directory location at [Put scala source files](https://github.com/saturday06/gradle-android-scala-plugin#4-put-scala-source-files).